# $A$ is measurable if and only if $\forall\epsilon$, $\exists$ open set $G$ and closed set $H$ such that $H\subset A\subset G$ and $\mu(G|H)<\epsilon$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let A be a real set then is it true that $A$ is measurable if and only if

$\forall\epsilon$, $\exists$ open set $G$ and closed set $H$

such that $H\subset A\subset G$ and $\mu(G|H)<\epsilon$.

Comment: This is the [regularity theorem for Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure).

Comment: Are you looking for a proof that Lebesgue measure is regular?

Comment: There a several equivalent def'ns of Lebesgue-measurable.This is one of them. Which def'n are you starting from?

Answer (score 0):

It is when $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

If $E$ is measurable then the open and closed set approximation is a consequence of the regularity of Lebesgue measure.

Conversely, since Lebesgue measure is complete and all Borel sets are measurable, if $E$ satisfies regularity condition, we can find $F\in F_\sigma,G\in G_\delta$ such that $\mu(G-F)=0,F\subset E\subset G$. Now $E=F\cup (E-F)$ and $E-F$ is contained in a measure zero set and thus measurable, so $E$ is also measurable.

Comment: Your answer proves the regularity of Lebesgue measure by assuming a different definition of regularity of Lebesgue measure and so is more aptly attached to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790871/regularity-of-a-measure). Here I think you should prove regularity without assuming it.

Comment: @hkBst since Lebesgue measure is uniquely defined, I'd take regularity as a natural property of it.